# d3.js - Transform hex color into darker tone hex color

Tags: d3.js

I would like to write a function to transform a rgb hex color (for example: #2eb82e) into a dark tone of that color.

```
d3.rgb(color).darker(1).toString();
```

The problem with the above line is that it doesn't return an rgb hex. It returns `rgb(46, 184, 46)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 now has a function for that:
https://github.com/d3/d3-color#color_formatHex

```
d3.rgb(color).darker(1).formatHex()
```